# Accessing property of parent class inside another template class

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct O {
    struct A {
        int a;
    };
    struct B: A {
        auto f() {
            this->a += 1; // OK
            a += 1;       // ERROR: 'a' was not declared in this scope
        }
    };
};
```

If I try to access `a` property of the base class using `this` pointer, compilation works great, but otherwise compiler does produce error: `'a' was not declared in this scope`.

Why does it happen?

P.S. Looks like it does work in MSVC, but does not work in GCC and Clang.

Comment: If the template declaration is removed, it compiles. Interesting!